# Python detecting error in code

Tags: python, error-handling

This snippet of python code has a lot of errors, but I wanted to know if someone can specifically explain to me what the "No global traceback found" error and "self is not first method argument?" The following occur on lines 16 and 28 respectively.

```
 1   #! /usr/bin/env python
 2
 3   'Example errors caught by PyChecker'
 4
 5   import string
 6
 7   metaslash = 1
 8
 9   def printNames():
10       neal = 'neal'
11       michelle = 'michele'
12       eric = 5
13       print "Local values: %(neal)S %(michele)s %(eric)" % locals()
14
15   class Nothing:
16       def printValue(value):
17           print value
18       def set(self, value):
19           self.value = value
20
21   def tryToDoSomething(self, value):
22       try:
23           import string
24           if not value:
25               raise RuntimeError, "Hey, there's no value"
26           printNames('a, b, c')
27       except:
28           traceback.print_exc()
29
30   def setGlobal(value=None):
31       print 'Old MetaSlash value is:', metaslash
32       metaslash = value
33       useless = Nothing(5)
34       print 'a useless value is:', useless.valeu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line 16 should be:

```
def printValue(self, value):
```

on line 28, what is this traceback object you are calling from? Python is not finding it.

Comment: Ok, figured it out and get what you're saying. What about line 16?

Comment: On line 16 you forgot the `self`, which every function within a class needs (see answer)

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be.  You could always decorate it with `@classmethod` to get around that.

Comment: yes that's true, but beginner pythoneers probably shouldn't mess around with decorators

Comment: Can you further explain the use of @classmethod ?

Comment: but seriously, you shouldn't use decorators unless you __absolutely__ need to in Python, and in this case you should just be passing the method `self`

Comment: ps: please choose this as the "answer" if it answered your question (little green checkmark), thanks!